# How to ignore raw loader for testing webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have some components with svg's loaded inline using webpack raw loader e.g...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import svg from '!raw!../assets/images/logo.svg'

export default class Logo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<a href={this.props.url} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: svg}} />)
  }
}
```

When trying to test these components server side using tape, they fall over. If I have css modules included, it is no problem, I can use [css-modules-require-hook](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules-require-hook/tree/master/demo) but svg's will not work. So I really need a raw loader require hook or something like that.

```
require('babel-register');
require('css-modules-require-hook/preset');
/* tests after this can import components with css includes */
```

I tried using [isomorphic-ensure](https://github.com/tomekwi/isomorphic-ensure) but this did not work.

```
require('babel-register');
require('css-modules-require-hook/preset');
require('isomorphic-ensure')({
  loaders: {
    raw: require('raw-loader'),
    raw: require('react-svgdom-loader')
  },
  dirname: __dirname
})
```

I get the following error:

`Cannot find module '!raw!../assets/images/`

Comment: Are you running your tests through webpack? If not, can you push the `import` outside of the module and inject it there (pass as a prop)? In case this doesn't work for you, could you consider something like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire)?

Comment: no I don't have a webpack config for my tests, just `require('babel-register');` then the `require( 'isomorphic-ensure')` then my list of component, action, reducer tests. e.g. `require('./components/Logo.spec.js');`

Comment: in my webpack.config for the actual app I have the following loader for svg's: `{ test: /\.svg$/, loaders: ['react-svgdom', 'svgo'] }`

Comment: Ok. To make it easier for you and avoid monkey-patching, consider pushing the webpack specific portion out of the module. If you want to retain the import, try [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire). I cannot guarantee it will work but it's worth a go at least.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using webpack for your tests then you could use the [ignore-styles module](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles).

You may have to configure it if you plan to use it with css-modules-require-hook as it will also also ignore [CSS files by default](https://github.com/bkonkle/ignore-styles/blob/master/ignore-styles.js#L1). e.g:

```
require('ignore-styles').register(['.svg'])
```